# Php, how to get parameters as a string (as I got?)

Tags: php, reflection

example:

```
$this->method ('1', 2, array(1,2,3), $this);

function method()
{
```

in `method()`, I want to get parameters just as I got them. I could use this:

```
foreach (func_get_args() as $item)
```

but thats not good this time. I simply want to get this string:

```
'1', 2, array(1,2,3), $this
```

is there any way?

Comment: why don't you pass them as string ?, like `$this->method ('\'1\', 2, array(1,2,3), $this');`

Comment: pass them as a string or build the string yourself. $s = ""; and in the for loop $s .= $item;

Comment: There is no way, since at execution time that "string" does not exist any more. PHP uses a compiler that converts the script into byte code. The original notation is lost during that step.

Comment: Can you give us any hint why would you need that at all? May be there is a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I am afraid that you will not solve your problems with this approach, but create even more problems instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approximation. You could open the code file for read and fetch the row containing the code as well. `debug_backtrace()` gives you the call stack with the information you need, e.g. code file name, line and name of function call.

```
<?php
function test()
{
  $trc = debug_backtrace();
  var_dump($trc); //See here what information you can obtain.
  //var_export($trc[0]['args']);
  echo preg_replace('~^\[(.*)]$~', '$1',  json_encode( $trc[0]['args'] ));
}

test('1',2, array(1,2,3), 'some string');
?>
```

> "1",2,[1,2,3],"some string"